# What is a spectrum object in $\infty$-topoi?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, topos-theory, infinity-topos-theory

For any spectrum $E$, there is a "discrete" topos spectrum $(Spaces / E_n)_n$. And I believe any topos spectrum is a localization of a "discrete" one. Are there any "non-discrete" topos spectra?

To be precise, let $Topoi$ be the $\infty$-category of $\infty$-topoi and geometric morphisms (pointing in the direction of the right adjoint). Note that $Spaces$ is terminal in $Topoi$. Let $Sp(Topoi)$ be the stabilization of this category: an object is a sequence $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ of pointed $\infty$-toposes equipped with equivalences $E_n = \Omega E_{n+1}$ where $\Omega$ is the loops functor on the category $Topoi_\ast$ of pointed toposes. The question is

**Question:** Are there examples of objects of $Sp(Topoi)$ other than the "discrete" ones referred to above?

As alluded to above, I think there is a major restriction on the possibilities: the $\Omega$ functor on pointed $\infty$-categories lands in spaces. Because the "presheaves" functor preserves limits, the $\Omega$ functor on presheaf toposes lands in slices of $Spaces$. Since every $\infty$-topos embeds in a presheaf topos and embeddings are stable under finite limits, this implies that if $(E_n)_n$ is a topos spectrum, then each $E_n$ embeds in (i.e. is a localization of) a slice of $Spaces$. I think this sounds pretty restrictive -- I don't know an example of a topos that embeds into a slice of $Spaces$ which is not itself a slice of $Spaces$!

Comment: Without much certainty, if G is a profinite abelian group I think the infinity topos completion of the topos of continuous action of G should fit into such a spectrum object without being etale.

Comment: I guess more generally any pro-objects in the infinity caregory of spectrum will realize into a spectrum in the category of infinity toposes

Comment: @SimonHenry That sounds promising. I wonder if more generally sheaves on a topological abelian group (locally compact, say) will give examples. It would be nice if $Sh(S^1)$ were a topos spectrum, for example. I wonder what kind of delooping machinery might work here...

Comment: @SimonHenry I know very little about the $\infty$-stuff but is not the homotopy category of $G$-spaces equivalent to the homotopy category of spaces over $BG$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : In general yes, but this is not exactly the same as the construction that I mentionned here. I'm starting from the topos of sets endowed with a continuous action of $G$, and then I take the infinity topos completion. The category that we obtain is more like a CW-complex or simplicial sets X such that G acts on $X$ by permutation of the cells and each cell is stabilised by an open subgroup. So if $G$ is non-discrete, its different.

Comment: @TimCampion : I would be very suprised if $Sh(S^1)$ were a spectrum. It clear is a "group like $E_{\infty}$-algebra", so if we were working inside an $\infty$-topos it would be a connective spectrum. But I'm almost certain it cannot be a loop space. Loop space of 1-topos (i.e localic automorphism groups of a point of a topos) are always prodiscrete in some sense, and that can never be $S^1$. I'm not sure exactly what can be said for $\infty$-topos though.

Comment: @SimonHenry Well you can still assign to such an $X$ the space $E(G,X):=(E(G)\times X)/G$, right? Going back is more technical (you must turn a space with a free $G$-action into an $X$ like in your comment) but maybe you can just prove that every free $G$-space is homotopy equivalent to $E(G,X)$ for some of your $X$?

Comment: I mean, this must work for any topological groups even, no?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე   I'm not exactly sure what goes wrong, but the kind of construction you are talking about has been developed to make sense up to weak homotopy equivalence. And up to weak homotopy equivalence a profinite group is a discrete group (and indeed, once you forget its topology, everything works as expected)

Comment: Umm I should be more careful - by homotopy type I should mean the one determined by the corresponding topos. For example, with $G=$ profinite integers, remembering the topology you get sets with permutations having all orbits finite, while forgetting the topology you get something much messier. I believe the homotopy types determined by these will be very different, no?

Comment: @SimonHenry Actually I am not even sure about your last comment - I mean, even in the "ordinary" sense, when $G$ is a profinite group, homotopy classes of maps to $BG$ with the topology of $G$ remembered should classify principal fibrations with fibres homeomorphic to $G$ with its given topology, while for $BG$ with discrete topology on $G$ these must classify just $G$-coverings, i. e. fibres must be discrete. I don't think there is an equivalence between these two groupoid-valued functors on spaces, or set-valued functors given by isomorphism classes of these groupoids either, is there one?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : To be honest I have no idea what $BG$ means (or if it exists) when $G$ is not a CW-complex or a simplicial group. I can't think of any definition of $BG$ that is not going to be weakly homotopy equivalent to the $BG$ for $G$ discrete : $\pi_n(BG)$ should be $\pi_{n-1}(G)$ which when $G$ is totally disconected makes $BG$ a $K(G,1)$ with $G$ discrete. If you use the "homotopy type of the topos" to define $BG$, then it makes sense, but you don't get an ordinary homotopy type, only a "pro-type" (but then it boils down to what I was talking about in the first place).

Comment: @TimCampion, This might be a stupid question, but how do you know that the functor $X \mapsto Spaces/X$ sends homotopy pullbacks of spaces to homotopy pullbacks of topoi? Looking at section 6.3.4 of HTT, the description of limits in RTop seems pretty complicated.

Comment: @YonatanHarpaz The argument I have in mind (which I hope is correct!) is the following: note that $Topoi(E, Psh(C)) = Flat(C, E)$ consists of functors $F: C \to E$ such that $Hom(e,F): C \to Spaces$ is flat, i.e. lies in $Ind(C^{op})$, for each $e \in E$. Since the functor $Cat \to Cat,\, C \mapsto Ind(C^{op})$ commutes with finite limits, it follows that $Psh: Cat \to Topoi$ commutes with finite limits.

Comment: @TimCampion, Can you give a bit more details (or a reference) about this statement (maybe I'm missing something, but I don't manage to see why it is true)?

Comment: @YonatanHarpaz My sense that this should be true comes from the explicit construction of PIE limits in the 1-categorical version of $Topoi$ in the _Elephant_, section B4. The fact that $Psh$ preserves finite products follows from HTT 7.3.3: Lurie shows the binary product in $Topoi$ is the Lurie tensor product of presentable categories, and $Psh(A) \otimes Psh(B) = Psh(A \times B)$. Let me run through my argument more slowly. A geometric morphism $E \to Psh(C)$ is(1) a left exact left adjoint $Psh(C) \to E$, which is (2) a flat functor $C \to E$ which is ...

Comment: @YonatanHarpaz ... (3) a functor $F: C^{op} \to E$ such that $Hom(e,F): C^{op} \to Spaces$ is contained in $Ind(C)$ for each $e \in E$. Now (4) $Ind: Cat \to Cat$ preserves finite limits, and likewise (5) $Flat((-)^{op},E): Cat \to Cat$ likewise preserves finite limits, so (6) $Topoi(E,Psh(-)): Cat \to Cat = Flat((-)^{op},E)$ preserves finite limits. I realize now I haven't carefully checked (5), only (4), so I might be wrong. Or maybe there's another part that's unclear?

Comment: Er -- something is clearly wrong in the passage from (2) to (3) where the "op" creeps in.

Comment: @TimCampion, I think you might be confusing two notions of flatness. According to nlab (under "flat functor"), a functor $F:C \to E$ to a topos $E$ induces a left exact functor $PSh(C) \to E$ if and only if $F$ is **internally flat** (that which is called a torsor in Johnstone). This is different from being **representably flat**, i.e., the property that $Hom(e,F)$ is flat for every $e \in E$. In particular, the former does not imply the latter in general. I'm starting to think that the premise of the question that $X \to Spaces/X$ preserves finite limits might be false.

Comment: @YonatanHarpaz You're right, this is a minefield. However the fact that $Spaces \to Topoi$, $X \mapsto Spaces /X$, preserves pullbacks, follows from HTT Rmk 6.3.5.8. This functor obviously preserves the terminal object, so it preserves all finite limits. But maybe it's not so clear that this is true for $Psh: Cat \to Topoi$ in general.

Comment: @TimCampion, Ah, yes, thanks! Actually, I should have realized this before. Indeed, the functor $X \to Spaces/X$ extends to a functor $Pro(Spaces) -> Topoi$ which is right adjoint to the shape functor (and hence preserves all limits), and the inclusion of $Spaces$ in $Pro(Spaces)$ preserves finite limits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up on the answer of Simon Henry, let us prove the following statement. For a pro-space $\hat{X} = \{X_i\}_{i \in I}$, we let $Spaces_{/\hat{X}}$ denote  the $\infty$-topos defined as the (cofiltered) limit in $Topoi$ of the $I$-family of étale topoi $Spaces_{/X_i}$. We will refer to such $\infty$-topoi as **pro-étale** $\infty$-topoi.

**Claim**: Suppose that ${\cal X}$ is an $\infty$-topos which is a loop object in $Topoi$. Then ${\cal X}$ is a left exact localization of a pro-étale $\infty$-topos $Spaces_{/\hat{X}}$ for $\hat{X} \in Pro(Spaces)$. If ${\cal X}$ is a double loop object then ${\cal X}$ itself is a pro-étale $\infty$-topos. In particular, every spectrum object in $Topoi$ consists of pro-étale $\infty$-topoi.

*Proof*:
Let ${\cal Y}$ be an $\infty$-topos equipped with two points $x_*,y_*: Spaces \to {\cal Y}$. Before considering the associated limit $Spaces \times_{\cal Y} Spaces$ we can consider the corresponding lax limit (or comma object) $Spaces \times^{\rm lax}_{\cal Y} Spaces$. We claim that this comma object exists and is furthermore a pro-étale $\infty$-topos. Indeed, let ${\cal Z}$ be an $\infty$-topos and let $p_*: {\cal Z} \to Spaces$ denote the terminal map. Then the data of a natural transformation $x_*p_* \Rightarrow y_*p_*$ is equivalent, by adjunction, to the data of a natural transformation $y^*x_* \Rightarrow p_*p^*$ of functors from $Spaces$ to $Spaces$. We note that both $y^*x_*$ and $p_*p^*$ are left exact functors and are hence corepresentable by pro-spaces, where the pro-space $Shp({\cal Z})$ corepresnting $p_*p^*$ is also known as the **shape** of ${\cal Z}$. Let $\hat{P}_{x,y} \in Pro(Spaces)$ denote the pro-space corepresenting $y^*x_*$. We then get that the data of a natural transformation $x_*p_* \Rightarrow y_*p_*$ is equivalent to the data of a map of pro-spaces $Shp({\cal Z}) \to \hat{P}_{x,y}$. We now recall that the formation of shapes ${\cal Z} \mapsto Shp({\cal Z})$ is left adjoint to the functor $\hat{X} \mapsto Spaces_{/\hat{X}}$ from pro-spaces to $\infty$-topoi. We may hence conclude that the data of a natural transformation $x_*p_* \Rightarrow y_*p_*$ is equivalent to the data of a geometric morphism ${\cal Z} \to Spaces_{/\hat{P}_{x,y}}$. We may then conclude that, if we let $q_*: Spaces_{/\hat{P}_{x,y}} \to Spaces$ be the terminal geometric morphism, then we have a canonical natural transformation $\tau:x_*q_* \Rightarrow y_*q_*$ which exhibits $Spaces_{/\hat{P}_{x,y}}$ as the desired comma object $Spaces \times^{\rm lax}_{\cal Y} Spaces$. Now let ${\cal P}_{x,y} \subseteq Spaces_{/\hat{P}_{x,y}}$ be the maximal left exact localization (see HTT 6.2.1.2) of $Spaces_{/\hat{P}_{x,y}}$ contained in the reflexive accessible subcategory 
$$\{X \in Spaces_{/\hat{P}_{x,y}} | \tau_X:x_*q_*X \to y_*q_*X \text{  is an equivalence}\} \subseteq Spaces_{/\hat{P}_{x,y}}.$$ 
Comparing universal properties we see that ${\cal P}_{x,y} \simeq Spaces \times_{\cal Y} Spaces$ represents the corresponding limit. In particular, for every points $x_*: Spaces \to {\cal Y}$ the loop $\infty$-topos ${\cal P}_{x,x} \simeq \Omega_x{\cal Y}$ is a left exact localization of a pro-étale $\infty$-topos.

Now suppose that ${\cal X}$ is an $\infty$-topos which is a double loop object, i.e., ${\cal X} \simeq \Omega_x{\cal Y}$ where ${\cal Y}$ itself is a loop object in $Topoi$. By the above we then have that ${\cal Y}$ is a left exact localization of pro-étale $\infty$-topos $Spaces_{/\hat{Y}}$, for some pro-space $\hat{Y} = \{Y_i\}_{i \in I} \in Pro(Spaces)$. Then $Spaces_{/\hat{Y}} = \lim_i Spaces_{/Y_i}$ and hence the space of points $y_*: Spaces \to Spaces_{/\hat{Y}}$ is naturally equivalent to the space $\lim_i Y_i = {\rm Map}_{Pro(Spaces)}(\ast,\hat{Y}) \in Spaces$. In this case, if $y_*: Spaces \to Spaces_{/\hat{Y}}$ corresponds to a compatible collection of points $y_i \in Y_i$ then
$$ \Omega_{y}Spaces_{/\hat{Y}} = \Omega_{y}\lim_i Spaces_{/Y_i} \simeq \lim_i \Omega_{y_i} Spaces_{/Y_i} \simeq  \lim_i Spaces_{/\Omega_{y_i} Y_i} = Spaces_{/\Omega_{y}\hat{Y}} .$$
Furthermore, if $y_*: Spaces \to Spaces_{/\hat{Y}}$ is a point which factors as $Spaces \stackrel{x_*}{\to} {\cal Y} \hookrightarrow Spaces_{/\hat{Y}}$ then $\Omega_y (Spaces_{/\hat{Y}}) \simeq \Omega_x {\cal Y}$. It then follows that ${\cal X} \simeq \Omega_x {\cal Y} \simeq Spaces_{/\Omega_y\hat{Y}}$ is a pro-étale $\infty$-topos, as desired.
$\Box$

**Remarks**:

1) At this point one may be tempted to conclude that every spectrum object in $Topoi$ is the image of a spectrum object in $Pro(Spaces)$. This is very possibly the case, but a-priori it does not follow from the above claim. All that can be deduced is that if we denote by $\widehat{Etale} \subseteq Topoi$ the full subcategory spanned by pro-étale topoi, i.e., the essential image of $Pro(Spaces) \to Topoi$, then every spectrum object in $Topoi$ comes from a spectrum object in $\widehat{Etale}$. However, since the functor $Pro(Spaces) \to \widehat{Etale}$ is not fully-faithful it is not a-priori clear if the map $Sp(Pro(Spaces)) \to Sp(\widehat{Etale})$ is essentially surjective. In other words, there could, in principle, be a spectrum object ${\cal X}_0,{\cal X}_1,...$ in $Topoi$ in which every ${\cal X}_i$ is a pro-étale spectrum ${\cal X}_1 \simeq Spaces_{/\hat{X}_i}$ but the structure equivalences $\varphi_i:{\cal X}_i \stackrel{\simeq}{\to} \Omega{\cal X}_{i+1}$ do not come from equivalences of pro-spaces $f_i:\hat{X}_i \stackrel{\simeq}{\to} \Omega\hat{X}_{i+1}$ (up to finitely many $\varphi_i$'s we can always arange it up to equivalence, but it's not clear if we can arrange all the $\varphi_i$'s at once; there is an obstruction to this which lies in a suitable $\lim^1$ set).

2) The claim that $Sh(S^1)$ is not an infinite loop object in $Topoi$ can be deduced from the above claim, at least if we assume that the truncation functor $\tau_{\leq 0}: Topoi \to Topoi_0$ from $\infty$-topoi to $0$-topoi (i.e., locales) preserves cofiltered limits (it seems to me that this claim should be deducible from the fact that cofiltered limits on both cases are computed in ${\rm Cat}_\infty$, see HTT 6.3.3.1). Assuming this, suppose that we had a CW complex $X$ such that $Sh(X)$ was an infinite loop object in $Topoi$. By the claim we have that $Sh(X) \simeq Spaces_{/\hat{X}} = \lim_i Spaces_{/X_i}$ for some pro-space $\hat{X} = \{X_i\}_{i \in I}$. By the commutativity of cofiltered limits and truncations we then have that the local $O(X)$ is equivalent to the local $\lim_i \tau_{\leq 0}(Spaces_{/X_i}) = \lim_i{\rm Sub}(\pi_0(X_i))$, where ${\rm Sub}(\pi_0(X_i))$ is the locale of subsets of $\pi_0(X_i)$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff it is sober and hence we may deduce that $X$ is homeomorphic to the limit $\lim_i \pi_0(X_i)$ (computed in topological spaces). But $X$ is a CW-complex and hence locally connected, and so $X \cong \lim_i \pi_0(X_i)$ would have to be a discrete set. In particular, $Sh(S^1)$ is not an infinite loop object (or even a double loop object).

Comment: Nice ! I can't remember why and I might be wrong, but I thought that pro-étale toposes were a reflexive subcategory of pro(spaces). If this is true that might help push things a bit further...

Comment: @SimonHenry, Really? That's interesting. In this case it would indeed imply that every spectrum object in $Topoi$ is the image of a spectrum object in $Pro(Spaces)$. Any ideas on how to find more information about this (googling is difficult because the words pro, etale and topoi appear mostly in configurations which have nothing to do with the pro-étale topoi we're talking about)?

Comment: Thanks this is great! It seems to me that in the course of the argument you calculated that the points of a pro etale topos are the same as the points of the underlying pro space. Since the functor from pro spaces to topoi is lex, I think this implies that the functor on spectrum objects is essentially surjective.

Comment: Very nice! Your characterization of loop ∞-topoi is related to the ∞-connected/algebraic factorization system on ∞-topoi (HTT 6.3.6). A point is always an algebraic geometric morphism, and these are stable under pullbacks, so loop ∞-topoi are algebraic. A localization of a pro-etale ∞-topos is clearly algebraic, and the claim in HTT 6.3.6.5 presumably implies the converse.

Comment: @SimonHenry I think warning 7.1.6.16 in htt indicates that this functor is not fully faithful, but it doesn’t give a counterexample

Comment: I don’t really understand this adjunction and Lurie doesn’t prove it. It comes down to showing that $ Topoi(X,Spaces/Y)=p_* p^* Y$ where $p^* \dashv p_*$ is the geometric morphism from $X$ to $Spaces$. Does anyone see why this is so?

Comment: @TimCampion : I don't think so: this wraning is about the fact that the realization functor Pro(Spaces)->Topos is not fully faithful (which is well known in the case of sets & locales and counterexamples are not too hard find). What I think might be fully faithful (but I still can't remeber why) is Lurie's Shape functor from "Pro-étale toposes" to Pro(Spaces). To put it another way I think the monads & comonads induced by the Shape/realization adjunction are both idempotent. (while Lurie's Warning is about the comonade not being trivial). But again I'm very not sure this is true.

Comment: @TimCampion See HTT 6.3.5.6.

Answer (score 3):

As you already noticed there is a functor from the category of Spectrum to the category of topos-spectrum, whose image consist simply of étale topos.

As the category of toposes has all limits one easily see that the category of topos spectrum also has all limits (they are computed component wise).

The functor from spectrum to topos spectrum commutes to finite limits, so it can be extended into a limit preserving functor from the category of pro-spectrum to the category of topos-spectrum (the functor that compute the formal limits).

I believe that this functor produces plenty of non-étale example of topos spectrum.

For example, if I take a profinite abelian group $G$, which I see as a formal cofiltered limits of finite abelian group $G = lim_k G_k$ then each finite abelian group $G_k$ can be seen as a connective spectrum (you can put either $G_k$ in degree $0$ or $1$, it is not making a bit difference) and this produces an example of a pro-spectrum.

Its realiziation in topos-spectrum is the projective limits of the toposes $G_k$ (or $BG_k$ depending on the degree) and hence the limits is the category of sheaves on $G$ (or the $\infty$-topos completion of the ordinary topos $BG$ of smooth action of $G$)

This topos is not étale.

More generally, it is shown in Sketches of an elephant (C5.1.12) that the localic reflection functor (from $1$-topos to locales) preserve cofiltered limits. Assuming that this also applies to the $n$-localic reflection functor of Lurie this gives an easy way to compute the $n$-topos truncation of (the $k$-level of) the topos-spectrum attached to a prospectrum (as it will appears as a cofiltered limits of discrete $\infty$-topos). Computing $0$-topos or $1$-topos truncation of such topos might be an easy way to show that lots of example constructed this way are not étale.

---

Regarding $Sh(S^1)$ or other connected abelian topological group, they are going to be group-like $E_{\infty}$-algebra in the category of toposes but I don't think they can be delooped.

In $1$-topos theory, the loop space of a pointed topos, corresponds to the localic group of automorphisms of the point, which is always a totally disconnected localic group. So it can never be a connected group.

It is not completely clear what is the situation with $\infty$-toposes but I don't expect it will be very different. This might be related to this [old question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155166/classifying-infty-toposes-for-topological-localic-groups) of mine and the answer by Jacob Lurie.

In fact because loop spaces of $\infty$-topos are expected to be totaly disconected and that there is a close connection between pro-abelian group and totally disconected abelian topological group, I suspect that there should be a close connection between topos-spectrum and pro-spectrum. (probably not an equivalence of categories, but not far from it). For example I can't think of any example of topos-spectrum that does not arise this way.